# Filtering NSFetchedResultsController results at runtime

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

What's the best way to implement runtime filtering of Core Data objects using NSFetchedResultsController?

For example, I want to be able to display all Record-entities in a RecordStore-entity, but also filter all Records in a RecordStore for some predefined critera, eg (ANY recordStore.records.count > 0).

I read that changing an NSFetchedResultsController's predicate after it has been created is bad. So should I store the fetched results in an NSArray that I can filter and use that as the UITableView's datasource, or should I create multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-fetch the data when you need to update. If the data itself changed, then you can just call fetch again. If your criteria changed, then set the predicate on your NSFetchedResultsController, and call fetch.

Comment: That means I would not be able to take advantage of the built-in cache of NSFetchedResultsController, and from my understanding, fetching is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Fetching is not particularly expensive especially when compared to keeping an array of fetched objects permanently in memory which is your other option in this case. The NSFetchedResultsController is usually useful only for large, relatively static tables. Don't  go looking for performance problems you might not have. Use the simplest solution first and then go for more complicated solutions only AFTER testings has shown the simplest solution won't work.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest property is a readonly property, so I don't think you can change your predicate because this belongs to the fetch request which is readonly.  Or concretely, how would you code this?

Comment: @horseshoe7 The NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest property being readonly just means you can't set a new instance of NSFetchRequest. However, the predicate property on the request is writeable, so you can simply set a new predicate and fetch data again to get the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create the NSFetchRequest instance, update request each time and perform fetch. Delete cache if you are using:

```
    let shortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending)


    fetchedResultViewController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [shortDescriptor]

    NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>.deleteCache(withName: fetchedResultViewController.cacheName)

    do {
        try fetchedResultViewController?.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error in fetch \(error)")
    }
```

Read the apple document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller